# Active developer path (\"/Applications/Xcode10.1.app/Contents/Developer\") does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, codenameone

I have an issue when I try to build the application IOS to CodenameOne Server, I get this error :

**Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode10.1.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist\nUse `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.\nSee `man xcode-select` for more details.\n")**

Anyone can help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We pushed a fix for this. This broke with our update to xcode on the servers as  required by Apple. It should work now.